# Unexpected result from Python function when using floats

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to create a Python class which change a numeric amount to french text.
I found a class which do this work but when the float is 50.4 per example, it returns "`Cinquante units et 399`.

The function toText takes 3 parameters: the float to convert, the unit, the decim.

```
def tradd(num):
    global t1,t2
    ch=''
    if num==0 :
        ch=''
    elif num<20:
        ch=t1[num]
    elif num>=20:
        if (num>=70 and num<=79)or(num>=90):
            z=int(num/10)-1
        else:
            z=int(num/10)
        ch=t2[z]
        num=num-z*10
        if (num==1 or num==11) and z<8:
            ch=ch+' et'
        if num>0:
            ch=ch+' '+tradd(num)
        else:
            ch=ch+tradd(num)
    return ch


def tradn(num):
    global t1,t2
    ch=''
    flagcent=False
    if num>=1000000000:
        z=int(num/1000000000)
        ch=ch+tradn(z)+' milliard'
        if z>1:
            ch=ch+'s'
        num=num-z*1000000000
    if num>=1000000:
        z=int(num/1000000)
        ch=ch+tradn(z)+' million'
        if z>1:
            ch=ch+'s'
        num=num-z*1000000
    if num>=1000:
        if num>=100000:
            z=int(num/100000)
            if z>1:
                ch=ch+' '+tradd(z)
            ch=ch+' cent'
            flagcent=True
            num=num-z*100000
            if int(num/1000)==0 and z>1:
                ch=ch+'s'
        if num>=1000:
            z=int(num/1000)
            if (z==1 and flagcent) or z>1:
                ch=ch+' '+tradd(z)
            num=num-z*1000
        ch=ch+' mille'
    if num>=100:
        z=int(num/100)
        if z>1:
            ch=ch+' '+tradd(z)
        ch=ch+" cent"
        num=num-z*100
        if num==0 and z>1:
           ch=ch+'s'
    if num>0:
        ch=ch+" "+tradd(num)
    return ch


def trad(nb, unite):
    global t1,t2
    x=int(nb)
    y=int((nb-x)*1000)
    t1=["","un","deux","trois","quatre","cinq","six","sept","huit","neuf","dix","onze","douze","treize","quatorze","quinze","seize","dix-sept","dix-huit","dix-neuf"]
    t2=["","dix","vingt","trente","quarante","cinquante","soixante","soixante-dix","quatre-vingt","quatre-vingt dix"]
    if x==0:
        ch="zéro"
    else:
        ch=tradn(abs(x))
    if x>1 or x<-1:
        if unite!='':
            ch=ch+" "+unite+'s'
    else:
        ch=ch+" "+unite

    if x<0:
        ch="moins "+ch
    return ch

def toText(nb, unite="Dinar", decim="millime"):
    x=int(nb)
    y=(nb-x)*1000
    z=int(y)

    if  y > 1:
        text_amount=trad(x,unite)+" et "+str(z)+" "+decim+"s"
    elif y==1:
        text_amount=trad(x,unite)+" et "+str(z)+" "+decim
    elif y==0:
        text_amount=trad(x,unite)+" et zéro "+decim
    return text_amount




if __name__=='__main__':

    print toText(45.4,"dinar")
```

Comment: The result of the function is correct. Can you please change the title to "Unexpected result... when using floats"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `z=int(y)` try using `z=int(round(y,0))`. That should round your 399.99... to 400.

```
>>> int(round((50.4-50.)*1000, 0))
400
```

Answer (score 2):

This is simply everyone's favorite old friend, floating-point error.

The lines:

```
x=int(nb)
y=int((nb-x)*1000)
```

end up doing:

```
(50.4-50)*1000 
# try this in your interpreter: 399.9999999999986
```

50.4 cannot be exactly represented with a (53-bit) floating-point number.  You will need to adjust accordingly via string formatting or rounding.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers already say, you cannot represent exactly floating point exactly with `float`, therefore `50.4` is printed as you see.

You can try to use the package [decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html): it is able to represent floating point exactly and you might be able to get the expected result

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `50.4` cannot be represented exactly:

```
>>> print('{:.47f}'.format(50.4))
50.39999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375
```

The fault is in the definition of the `toText` function. The lines:

```
x=int(nb)
y=(nb-x)*1000
z=int(y)
```

will result in `z` being `399` instead of `400`.

If you want to give more "user-friendly" output you'd have to manually check whether the fractional part is "strange" and rounding accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `round`

```
def toText(nb, unite="Dinar", decim="millime"):
    x=int(nb)
    y=(nb-x)*1000
    z=int(round(y))
```